# Beamer: Right align Section Title in in Headline of Beamer

Tags: beamer, headline

I want to create a beamer presentation for my mathematics notes taking in which such that the section of each section is shown in the headline of each page with the section number. Further, I want this section title must be right-aligned (as shown in the figure) with page setting a4 (landscape). I have tried different themes like metropolis, CambridgeUS and many others but can not find the solution.

my Code is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[size=a4,orientation=landscape,scale=3.5]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{metropolis}
\setbeamertemplate{frame numbering}[fraction]
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

%\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{.125,.5,.25}
\usecolortheme[named=mygreen]{structure}

\setbeamersize
{
    text margin left=4.5cm,
    text margin right=2cm
}

\begin{frame}[t]{Functions} \vspace{4pt}
asdjhas djasasd asdajskdjaksd aksjdkasjd 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could define your own headline template. Here just something simple to add the section number and name. You can modify it to whatever layout you want:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[size=a4,orientation=landscape,scale=3.5]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{multicol}

\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]
\usecolortheme{spruce}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

%\definecolor{mygreen}{rgb}{.125,.5,.25}
\usecolortheme[named=green]{structure}

\setbeamersize
{
    text margin left=4.5cm,
    text margin right=2cm
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\Huge\hfill\insertsectionnumber~\insertsectionhead}

\begin{document}
\section{title}

\begin{frame}[t]{Functions} \vspace{4pt}
asdjhas djasasd asdajskdjaksd aksjdkasjd 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```